# Why can we model the stock price as random error around a bond price?

Tags: finance

Right now I am taking a course on financial math and we want to model the stock price.

For continuous compound interest we have the formula $B(t) = b_0 e^{rt}$ where $r$ denotes the interest rate and $b_0$ the initial principal.

Now we want to create a model for the stock price and do so by assuming that the stock price results from a random error $\epsilon$ around a bond price with another interest rate $\tilde{r}$.

This leads to the following plain model for the stock price: $S(t) = s_0 e^{\tilde{r}t + \epsilon}$

This model gets more and more refined over the lecture(especially the properties of our error $\epsilon$) but there are two things a don't get:

1. Where does this assumption come from that the stock price roughly behaves like a bond price?
2. Why is it $S(t) = s_0 e^{\tilde{r}t + \epsilon}$ and not for example $S(t) = s_0 e^{\tilde{r}t} + \epsilon$?

Comment: That is a finance specific question, not mathematics, but the simple assumption is that stock prices might be expected to grow steadily over time, combined with some noise.  The noise is in a sense multiplicative (e.g. $\pm 20\%$) rather than additive

Comment: There's no bond here...bonds have stated maturity and coupons.  This (very stripped down model) just says that stocks drift up steadily with some noise. 
 More broadly, you can model a stochastic process anyway you like...the question is whether you can sensibly calibrate your model to the market.  Can you parametrize your model in a practical and sensible manner.  Here, you'd want to match forward prices and maybe some options.

Comment: Note too that $e^{rt+\epsilon}=e^{rt}e^{\epsilon}\approx e^{rt}\times (1+\epsilon)$ if $\epsilon$ is small so the model you propose isn't terribly different.

Comment: Another reason to use the exponential form is that we want stock prices to stay non-negative. Nonetheless: a model named after [Louis Bachelier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Bachelier) where stock prices follow a Brownian motion (not geometric) is of great historical interest.